# Excel unable to open SSAS Reporting Action

Tags: excel, ssas, action, reporting

I have created a Reporting Action on my SSAS cube and deployed the Reporting Project to my Report Server. The Report has a parameter and I can manually insert it into the report and it works just fine. However, when I am trying to pass the parameter from the Excel and run the Reporting Action I get an error that reads:

Unable to open

http:////:command=render&rs:Render=HTML5.Cannot download the information you requested.

What is this error message? How to fix it?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the action setup and the MDX expressions used.

Comment: The Action setup is added.

Comment: In your PivotTable what Customer attribute is on rows? Customer Key or some other customer attribute?

Comment: Customer Key is in the row

Comment: well, just fixed it. My Parameter name was spelled incorrectly and didn't match the QueryParameter name in the rdl file.